# A PDF reader - please guide - a step by step guidance - reference to guidance-

Tags: pdf, hardware, microcontroller

I have to make a hardware project using a microcontroller, memory, screens, etc.

Is it possible to make an independent PDF / documents reader, which is capable of running on battery power?

Please note I don't want to use any technology which needs licensing. It must be all freeware readers, etc., and programing language can be assembly, C, Flash or any.

I have submitted proposal of PDF reader project (independent hardware). Many say it's impossible. What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading and displaying a PDF document is quite a "high level operation".

You should start with a microcontroller starter kit, with an ARM9 processor or something similar. Then install a Linux operating system on it, include a standard display driver and run an X server. Then you should be able to find a Linux based PDF reader with X drivers.

Answer (score 0):

To 2nd another comment here, I would say that you're not going to to do this with a microcontroller, you're going to need to get some more powerful ARM CPU like an ARM9, Cortex-A8 or similar with a decent amount of RAM.

You'll probably need something that's capable of running Linux if you want to start with pieces of software that won't require writing quite a large volume of software from scratch.

Note that for commercial devices that are out there, including the Kindle, run Linux, and aren't based on a micrcontroller.

You might be best off getting something like a BeagleBoard, attach a display to that, and start from there with an X-based PDF viewer.

Comment: You could also look into www.armkits.com  They have quite a few boards that come with LCD's and Linux installed.